# Frequency table comparison using R

Tags: r, data-visualization, frequency

I have two frequency tables created using `R`'s `table()` function:

```
freq1 <- table(unlist(strsplit(topic_list1, split=";")))
freq2 <- table(unlist(strsplit(topic_list2, split=";")))
```

`topic_list1` and `topic_list2` are strings that contains textual representations of topics separated by `;`.

I want a way to compare the two frequencies, graphically if possible.

So if the two lists contain the same topic with different frequencies, I would like to be able to see it. The same goes for topics present in one frequency table, but not in the other.

Comment: To help you get your question answered on SO: provide a small example data set that can be pasted directly into R (e.g. extract a small amount of your data into another variable or variables, and use `dput`).

Comment: If we interpret this as a question of data visualization it will admit answers of general interest (beyond just `R` programming) and thereby becomes suitable for this site.

Comment: Thanks, I flagged this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but this ought to work:

```
# here I'm generating some example data
set.seed(5)
topic_list1 <- paste(sample(letters, 20, replace=T), sep=";")
topic_list2 <- paste(sample(letters, 15, replace=T), sep=";")

# I don't make the tables right away
tl1      <- unlist(strsplit(topic_list1, split=";"))
tl2      <- unlist(strsplit(topic_list2, split=";"))
big_list <- unique(c(tl1, tl2))

# this computes your frequencies
lbl         <- length(big_list)
tMat1       <- matrix(rep(tl1, lbl), byrow=T, nrow=lbl)
tMat2       <- matrix(rep(tl2, lbl), byrow=T, nrow=lbl)
tMat1       <- cbind(big_list, tMat1)
tMat2       <- cbind(big_list, tMat2)
counts1     <- apply(tMat1, 1, function(x){sum(x[1]==x[2:length(x)])})
counts2     <- apply(tMat2, 1, function(x){sum(x[1]==x[2:length(x)])})
total_freqs <- rbind(counts1, counts2, counts1-counts2)

# this makes it nice looking & user friendly
colnames(total_freqs) <- big_list
rownames(total_freqs) <- c("topics1", "topics2", "difference")
total_freqs           <- total_freqs[ ,order(total_freqs[3,])]
total_freqs
            d  l  a  z  b f s y m r x h n i g k c v o
topics1     0  0  0  0  0 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
topics2     2  2  2  1  1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
difference -2 -2 -2 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

From there you could just use the straight numbers or visualize them however you want (e.g, dotplots, etc.).  Here's a simple dotplot:

```
windows()
  dotchart(t(total_freqs)[,3], main="Frequencies of topics1 - topics2")
  abline(v=0)
```

[image]

Comment: This might be a great SO answer, but on this site it at least needs some explanation about what it's doing. You seem to be dodging the key part of the question: exactly how can one visualize the results?

Comment: I suppose I'm assuming it will end up migrated. The difference in the counts is "a way to compare the two frequencies". As far as how to compare them graphically, that seems obvious at this point, but I can add a plot.

Comment: I was thinking that the question of graphical display might be open to some creative answers :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply barplot them (with beside=T argument), which will give you a way to visually compare the counts per level ...
below is an example:

```
counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, col=c("darkblue","red"), legend=rownames(counts), beside=T)
```